MQTTのクライアント識別について
今現在の状況
MQTTのブローカーを作成しています。
パケットを作成し、送信したり受けとったりなどの処理はできています。
疑問点
ブローカ側でサブスクライブを送ってきたクライアントと購読したいトピックをブローカでどのように識別、紐付けを行うのかが不明です。
ClientID
初めはconnectコマンドの際のクライアントIDで識別すると思っていました。

しかしこの値は任意であるので、違うと判断しました。
参考文献 : MQTT V3.1 プロトコル仕様
Mosquitte内のコード
if(context->in_packet.command != (CMD_SUBSCRIBE|2)){
        return MOSQ_ERR_MALFORMED_PACKET;
    }

    log__printf(NULL, MOSQ_LOG_DEBUG, "Received SUBSCRIBE from %s", context->id);


mosquitteのソースコードを読んでみると、どこからサブスクライブパケットを送信しているのかログに出力する箇所を見つけました。
関数をさかのぼってみましたが、よくわかりませんでした。
知りたいこと
MQTTのブローカは、どのようにしてクライアントを一意に識別しているのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。
